# Loading spring XML from location different from classpath to get a bean in Servlet

Tags: java, spring, jakarta-ee, spring-mvc

I have a `Servlet` class that is supposed to get data from service and write the data back  to servlet response. The `service` class is already declared in spring xml (`dispatcher-servlet.xml`). So I want to get the `service class bean` from `dispatcher-servlet.xml`.

I tried below code

```
            ApplicationContext context = new FileSystemXmlApplicationContext("classpath:../WebContent/WEB-INF/dispatcher-servlet.xml");
        ServiceImpl serviceImpl = (ServiceImpl) context.getBean("service");
```

and below code

```
            ServletContextResource res = new ServletContextResource(getServletContext(),"/WEB-INF/dispatcher-servlet.xml");
        ApplicationContext context = new FileSystemXmlApplicationContext("file:"+res.getURL()+"dispatcher-servlet.xml");
        ServiceImpl serviceImpl = (ServiceImpl) context.getBean("service");
```

but those these are throwing `FileNotFoundException`

If I move the `dispatcher-servlet.xml` to `src` folder, it works fine. But I can't move it because the dispatcher-servlet.xml has been there in WEB-INF for long time many other classes are using it. `dispatcher-servlet.xml` is declared in Web.xml properly and it loads and works properly.

Only issue is I am unable to load it from the java code in servlet class.

The location of the dispatcher-xml is /WebContent/WEB-INF/dispatcher-servlet.xml

Any pointers or workarounds are highly appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: Read about what the classpath is and which parts of a web app are added to the classpath and which aren't.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`WEB-INF` is added to classpath

You can try below code

```
ApplicationContext context = new FileSystemXmlApplicationContext
              ("classpath:/../dispatcher-servlet.xml");
```

Consider reading about what the classpath is and which parts of a web app are added to the classpath as advised by [Sotirios Delimanolis](https://stackoverflow.com/users/438154/sotirios-delimanolis)

Comment: It works with ClassPathXmlApplicationContext, thanks

Answer (score 0):

In your servlet code, have you tried:

```
ApplicationContext context = WebApplicationContextUtils.getWebApplicationContext(getServletContext(),
"org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.CONTEXT.dispatcher");
```

You'll need to ensure that your servlet is initialised after the dispatcher servlet in the web.xml (use the `load-on-startup` element).